# Swift AutoLayout Problems With Nav Bar

Tags: swift

I'm starting in Swift, I have some problems with my navigation bar at Swift.

Maybe it's OK in device but here in simulator it's not. Could someone help me to fix this? I tried some constraints but didn't work.

Follow the print:

[image]

Comment: Your device is iphone 6?

Comment: Yes in the simulator I tried with 6 and 5s